# How can I get a number based on user input to show in the html text I have at the bottom of the page?

Tags: java, html, css

The doughnut graph has a green section called group ltd plan but that shows a full years calculation. I want to show the monthly group ltd plan which would be the green group ltd number from the doughnut chart divided by 12. I am having difficulty getting the number to print where I wrote "Monthly group ltd plan:" the number is not appearing. I have tried using document.write and .innerhtml which is what I currently have in my code. If anyone could help show me what I am doing wrong that would be great, thanks!

```js
function hpmpGraph() {
  var hp = document.hpmpForm.HP.value,
    np = hp * .6,
    cp = hp - np,
    rp = hp / 12,
    mp = document.hpmpForm.MP.value,
    ap = +mp + +cp,



    ctx = document.getElementById('hpmpratio').getContext('2d');
  var data = {
    labels: ["Income at Risk", "Group LTD Plan"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [ap, np],
      backgroundColor: ["#D9221C", "#17DB4E"],
      hoverBackgroundColor: ["#D9221C", "#17DB4E"]

    }]
  };
  var options = {
    cutoutPercentage: 65
  };
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: options

  });
}

function myFunction() {
  var number = 12;
  document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = number;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> How much of your income is at risk?
  </title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    input[type='text'] {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="hpmpGraph()" onload="myFunction()" style="background-color:F3FBFF;text-align:center">
  <h1 style="text-align:center">
    <font face="Verdana" color="2D4C5E" size="9">How much of your income is at risk?</font><br />
  </h1>
  <form name="hpmpForm" method="post">
    Salary :
    <input type="text" name="HP" value="180000">
    <br> Bonus & Commision :
    <input type="text" name="MP" value="50000">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="hpmpGraph();">Calculate</button>
    <h3>Results</h3>
    <canvas id="hpmpratio" height="85"></canvas>
  </form>
  <p>
    <font color="#17DB4E">Monthly Group LTD Plan: <span id="myText"></span> </p>
  <p>
    <font color="#D9221C">Unprotected Monthly Income:</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to remove your onloads and instead use an eventListener and have the functions in there `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  hpmpGraph(); myFunction()}); `

Comment: Also put the inline styles in the style tags or external stylesheet

Answer (score -1):

You can only have one onload function in body. I'm just making addition to code what you need to do, you can actually run myfunction() inside hpmpGraph() function like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> How much of your income is at risk?
    </title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script> 
    <style>
        input[type='text'] { font-size: 14px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="hpmpGraph()" style="background-color:F3FBFF;text-align:center">
    <script>
        function hpmpGraph() {
           var hp = document.hpmpForm.HP.value,
              np = hp * .6,
              cp = hp - np,
              rp = hp/12,
              mp = document.hpmpForm.MP.value,
              ap = +mp + +cp,
              
              
              
              ctx = document.getElementById('hpmpratio').getContext('2d');
           var   data = {
              labels: ["Income at Risk","Group LTD Plan"],
              datasets:
                 [{
                    data: [ap,np],
                    backgroundColor: ["#D9221C","#17DB4E"],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: ["#D9221C","#17DB4E"]
                    
                 }]
           };
           var options = {cutoutPercentage: 65};
           var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'doughnut',
              data: data,
              options: options  
              
           });
           myFunction()
        }
                    
        function myFunction() {
        var number = 12;
        document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = number;
        document.getElementById("mIncome").innerHTML = "$100000";
        }
        
        
    </script> 
    <h1 style="text-align:center"><font face = "Verdana" color = "2D4C5E" size = "9">How much of your income is at risk?</font><br />
    </h1>
    <form name="hpmpForm" method="post">
        Salary : 
        <input type="text" name="HP" value="180000">
        <br>
        Bonus & Commision : 
        <input type="text" name="MP" value="50000">
        <br> 
        <button type="button" onclick="hpmpGraph();">Calculate</button> 
        <h3>Results</h3>
        <canvas id="hpmpratio" height="85"></canvas>
    </form>
    <p> <font color = "#17DB4E" >Monthly Group LTD Plan: <span id="myText"></span> </p>
    <p> <font color = "#D9221C">Unprotected Monthly Income: <span id="mIncome"></span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Great you suggest to move the function, but you really also should suggest to not have ANY inline event handlers, especially in the body

Comment: Just mentioned something that works, you can use inline handlers in such simple cases and they work.

Comment: such cases become more complex and then they blow up when installing a crappy plugin

Comment: thanks jjsingh this worked out for me! mplungjan I will take your advice and make an external style sheet

Comment: welcome, Please upvote the answer if it helped you. Regarding best practices, you can probably have a complete handbook.

Comment: unfortunately I am a new user and it does not let me upvote yet jjsingh